# eval command is not working for me

Tags: tcl

```
% set a
1
% set a
1
% set 1
puts hai
%

% puts [eval "$$a"]
invalid command name "puts hai"
%
%
%
% puts [eval [subst "$$a"]]
hai
%
```

In this case the command

```
% puts [eval "$$a"]
invalid command name "puts hai"
%
```

the above command is not working .. can anyone please .. find the issue with this statement .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had `puts` twice--that's the problem:

```
% set 1
puts hai

% set a
1

% eval $1; # de-reference
hai

% eval [set 1]; # another way to de-reference
hai


% eval [set $a]; # Double de-reference
hai
```

Comment: "eval $$a" This command should work right ? , Tcl interpreter intially pass through the command and will substitute the "$a" value first , In the second time  eval is going to work , eval command should substitute the variable before it execute the command ..

Comment: `eval $$a` does not work. Tcl interpreter only do variable substitution once. During that one time, the expression becomes `eval $1`, but the interpreter will not substitute again, thus `$1` will not become `puts hai`.

Comment: Whatever you said is correct .. 
But I am getting the output as invalid command . i.e , $1 value is substituting
'% eval $$a              



invalid command name "puts hai"
%'

Comment: The `[set $a]` is the *official* way to do double dereferencing.